Unexpected Token - why is it happening and how to get rid of the error
I made a gui using javafx and scene builder. My current task is to call info from a class so I can display it in my gui. I initialized 3 objs in an array, and now I am trying to create the objects, using a for loop. However, I get "unexpected token" error when I write the for loop. There are no redlines or syntax errors that I can see.
This is my code (bold face is where the error occurs):
package com.example.moonbucksgui4;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class GUIController {
    @FXML
    private Label drinkText;
    @FXML
    private Label mugText;
    @FXML
    private Label gcText;

    private Drinks[] drinksMenu = new Drinks[3];
    private String[] names = {"Cappuccino", "Latte", "Hot Chocolate"};

    /* Drink Info */
    private int[] calories = {60,130,320};
    private String[] sizes = {"Tall","Grande","Venti"};
    private double[] fat = {0.1, 0.3, 3.0};
    private int[] sugar = {8,18,55};
    private double[] price = {5.99, 10.99, 15.35};

    /* Drink Classes */
    for(int i=0; i < drinksMenu.length; i++)


    @FXML
    protected void drinkButtonClick(){
        drinkText.setText("These are Drinks");
        mugText.setText("");
        gcText.setText("");
    }
    @FXML
    protected void mugButtonClick(){
        mugText.setText("These are mugs");
        drinkText.setText("");
        gcText.setText("");
    }
    @FXML
    protected void gcButtonClick(){
        gcText.setText("These are Gift Cards");
        drinkText.setText("");
        mugText.setText("");
    }
}



A for loop is executable code. It has to be placed somewhere in the Java file that is executable (method, constructor, etc.)

This looks like something that may need to be in a public void initialize();. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html

As pointed out by SedJ601, instructions for initializing fields in a controller go in an initialize() method in the controller:
public void initialize() {
    for (int i=0; i < drinksMenu.length; i++) {
        drinksMenu[i] = new Drink(names[i], calories[i], sizes[i], fat[i], sugar[i], price[i]);
    }
}

By convention, the FXMLLoader will invoke the initialize method on the controller, either if the method is declared public like above or if the method is private and has the @FXML annotation.  When you use the FXML annotation, you also need to open the package containing your controller to FXML.
However, in your example the drinks themselves are data, so probably should not be initialized in the controller at all. The drinksMenu could be created elsewhere in the application and passed to the controller.  I won't provide code for that here, but you can consult the linked resources if interested.
For small amounts of hard-coded data, like in your example, you can initialize it inline without a loop like this:
record Drink(
        String name,
        int calories,
        String size,
        double fat,
        int sugar,
        BigDecimal price
) {}

private final List<Drink> drinks = List.of(
        new Drink("Cappuccino", 60, "Tall", 0.1, 8, new BigDecimal("5.99")),
        new Drink("Latte", 130, "Grande", 0.3, 18, new BigDecimal("10.99")),
        new Drink("Hot Chocolate", 320, "Venti", 3.0, 38, new BigDecimal("15.35"))
);

I used BigDecimal instead of double to represent price, as BigDecimal is better suited for representing a monetary value.
